# Duplicate Method Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, syntax

I'm very new to Objective-C and the syntax and everything. I wrote two separate methods, but ran into the error: `Duplicate declaration of method webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`
So, it looks like I need to combine both of my `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` methods. The only issue is, they both contain if statements and return values, and that super confused me. These are the two methods:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *full = [request.URL absoluteString];

    if ([full isEqualToString:@"ExampleURL.com"] || [full isEqualToString:@"ExampleURL.com"]
        || [full isEqualToString:@"ExampleURL.com"] ) {

        return YES;
    }
    else
        return NO;    

}
```

And:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSString *full = [request.URL absoluteString];

    if ([full isEqualToString:@"ExampleURL.com"]) {
        _backButton.hidden = YES;
        return NO;
    } else {
        _backButton.hidden = NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I've been trying to combine these two methods into one for a long time now, and am at a loss. It's the `if` statements that are tripping me up. Does anyone know how I could do this or what it would look like?

Side note: My desired goal is to only allow specific URLs to load. At the same time, I need the back button to be hidden only when one website is loaded. Does anyone know if there would be a way to hide / show the back button based on a URL by avoiding this method all together? I think I may be going about this wrong.

Comment: Your goals seem contradictory. In one function, you're returning `YES` when seeing `"ExampleURL.com"` but in the other function you're returning `NO` when seeing `"ExampleURL.com"`. Which do you want?

Comment: In plain english what is your desired logic when a webview starts loading, because these 2 implementations contradict each other.

Comment: @AlexWayne My desired goal is to only allow specific URLs to load. At the same time, I need the back button to be hidden only when one website is loaded.

Comment: It's not clear that it's at issue here, but it should be pointed out that if you have several DIFFERENT web view objects, you can compare the web view pointer that is the first parm to your object pointers, to see which one the method was invoked on behalf of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSString *full = [request.URL absoluteString];

    if([full isEqualToString:@"hidebackbuttonforthiswebsite.com"])
        _backButton.hidden = YES;

    if ([full isEqualToString:@"AcceptedURL1.com"] ||
        [full isEqualToString:@"AcceptedURL2.com"] ||
        [full isEqualToString:@"AcceptedURL3.com"]) 
    {
        // Good URL, load it
        return YES;
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Bad URL, so don't load it
        return NO;
    }
}
```

This will hide the back button for the specific URL, and then allow only a specific set of URLS to load. It sounded like this is what you want, but it's hard to understand your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

What's your desired logic here? One method will be called when the WebView starts loading.  You will do some stuff, then return `YES` or `NO` based on whether you want the loading to proceed.  You *can't* tell it it's ok to load and then tell it that it's not ok to load at the same time.

In your two methods you have this:

```
if ([full isEqualToString:@"ExampleURL.com"] || ...snipped... ) {
    return YES;
}
```

And then this

```
if ([full isEqualToString:@"ExampleURL.com"]) {
    // ...
    return NO;
}
```

Which check the same thing but then return opposite values.

---

So I'll answer generally.  This is sort of the general form of this method.

```
-(BOOL)                webView:(UIWebView *)webView
    shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    // alter application state
    // return YES or NO
}
```

Lets say you want to do this, which I'm not sure is what you want, but this is the general idea:

- if loading ExampleURL.com, then show the back button and allow the load
- otherwise, hide the button and do not allow the load.

Then you might implement this method like so:

```
-(BOOL)                webView:(UIWebView *)webView
    shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([[request.URL host] isEqualToString:@"ExampleURL.com"]) {
        _backButton.hidden = NO;
        return YES;
    } else {
        _backButton.hidden = YES;
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Now adjust that to reflect the logic you *actually* want.

Comment: Awesome thanks you so much for your answer Alex, incredibly detailed and helpful. My desired goal is to only allow specific URLs to load. At the same time, I need the back button to be hidden only when one website is loaded. I will take a wack at this referencing the code you wrote, but it is far over my head. I'm still learning as I go. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you know if there would be a way to hide / show the back button based on a URL by avoiding this method all together? I think I'm going about this wrong.

Comment: If you want to take action based when a url wants to start loading, this is the method where you would do that.  Just realize you are doing 2 things in one method, altering application state (hiding the back button, or not), and deciding if the url should be allowed to load (returning YES or NO).  And you do both those things in one method.  Just make sure the `return` as at the ends, as that will exit execution of the method.

Answer (score 1):

I general, you might consider an additional conditional inside the method to determine what condition tree to use. 
That could be another method called within this one. 
You might also consider adding an additional argument to the method parameters if you need some criterion to determine conditional logic inside the method. 
Another option, if you have two methods that cannot be merged because they do different things, but they have the same argument list, you should change the selectors (method signature) to distinguish them and make sure the selector indicates what they do differently.

Comment: Good advice, thank you. I have absolutely no idea how to do that, I'm still pretty new but I will research!

Comment: Basically, this is called refactoring. Since one method can call another method, it's always good to try to refine the flow. Try to keep code you see as concise as possible to understand a block of it. If it gets too long or complex in one method or function, it's usually a good time to break out portions of it into other methods or functions. It takes practice, and seeing other people's code. I recommend Steven Kochan's book on Programming in Objective-C